# MKMapView setRegion:animated doesn't work on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a problem with animation in function `setRegion:animated:`.

```
CLLocationRegion *region = self.mapView.region;  <br>
region.center = newCoordinate; // newCoordinate actually is in region<br>
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

When I test the app on iPhone 4 , everything is work fine,
but in iPhone 5 animation is performed successfully only when the region's current coordinate is down of `newCoordinate`. If region's current coordinate is up of `newCoordinate`, then `setRegion` works without animation, like

```
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:NO].
```

image: http://s11.postimg.org/6jdnvkxw3/image.jpg

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by up and down? North and south?

Comment: Which iOS version (exactly) is installed on these two devices?